# How to uninstall Puppeteer npm

Tags: javascript, npm, puppeteer

I had installed Puppeteer a while back on an express api for heroku and I was using their heroku git cli, I've now removed the puppeteer from the package.json file and run npm install and tried to push to github but it still seems to be writing the local chromium file which is too big for github to handle, is there a way to remove puppeteer completely?

Thanks

Comment: normally `npm uninstall <name of the package>` is all you need to do, but I'm very suspicious of the rest of your description... what file are you talking about exactly that is too big for github to handle?

Comment: remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1629/1629), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 27ee4340d628d3d86f565d01c724e5cf
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-756035/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Framework.framework/Versions/83.0.4103.0/Chromium Framework is 182.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB - This is what I get when trying to push

Comment: I don't seem to have puppeteer in my package.json so not sure why it's trying to load that file, I also can't even seem to find that file in the project directory, I tried to CD into it and it was not found

Answer (score 0):

If `npm uninstall puppeteer` does not work, you can delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. This will reinstall every module from scratch.

If you already staged/commited that file, you could remove then by running `git rm -rf path/to/file --cached`.